# Python quickie: decimal point precision equality

Tags: python, precision

Hello I have a quick question before I go and do a complicated loop full of type conversions and stuff.

While comparing two values, will this result in `True`?

`0.1 == 0.10` (in floating point)

I'm really comparing members of a list and they might come out like this and I just wanted to make sure equal values will result in true for my if statements

Will this result in true or would I need to change the decimal point precision for one of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `0.1 == 0.10` in IDLE and it will show that it evaluates to true.

Same goes for `0.1 == 0.10000`, this will evaluate to true.

Comment: Yeah I'm really comparing members of a list and they might come out like this and I just wanted to make sure equal values will result in true for my if statements.

Comment: If the value in the list is 0.1 or 0.100 or something to that effect it will be true when compared with 0.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing decimal arithmetic that needs to be exact, unlike float, use the Decimal type.